# IE, tabbing out of open dropdown trumps visible binding in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, knockout.js

In IE11, if you hit tab when you're focused on an **open** `<select>` dropdown, the dropdown will close and focus will move ahead to the next control in the tab index. This is unlike Chrome, where the same action will just close the dropdown and require that you hit tab again to advance.

My trouble is in the case when the next control is being revealed by the knockoutjs "visible" data-bind. IE skips over the newly revealed control and onto the next!

```
<select data-bind="value: dDown">
    <option></option>
    <option>Fred</option>
    <option>Barney</option>
    <option>None</option>
</select>

<select data-bind="visible: dDown">
    <option>Can</option>
    <option>You</option>
    <option>Dig</option>
</select>   

Land here: <input type="text" />
```

My knockout is like so:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    this.dDown = ko.observable(false);
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

I've been able to brute force with a `e.keyCode == 9`, `e.preventDefault()` type of handler on all of my html control elements. Pretty ugly. Wondering if there's a way to enhance the visible knockout binding? Or even a IE setting that changes the tab behavior?

Any help is most appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok changed my answer. the only way i could get it to work was a delay on setting focus. so I created a writable observable that delays the focus. run the snippet below.  seemed to work for me I don't have ie11 but I used an emulator.

```js
function vm() {
  var self = this;
  this.records = ko.observableArray();
  this.availableNames = ko.observableArray(['Fred', 'Barney']);
  this.availableOptions = ko.observableArray(['Can', 'You', 'Dig']);
  this.selectedName = ko.observable('');
  this.selectHasFocus = ko.observable(false);
  this.dDown = ko.observable(false);
  
  this.selectedNameComputed = ko.pureComputed({
        read: function () {
            return self.selectedName();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            this.selectedName(value);
            if (self.selectedName()){
             self.dDown(true);
             self.selectHasFocus(true) 
             setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('myselect').focus(); }, 10);
            }else{
              self.dDown(false);
            }
            
        },
        owner: this
    });

}

var myViewModel = new vm();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  input1: <input/>
</p>

<select data-bind="options: availableNames,
optionsCaption: 'None', value: selectedNameComputed">
</select>

<select data-bind="options: availableOptions, visible: dDown, hasFocus: selectHasFocus " id="myselect">

</select>
</p>
<p>
  input2: <input>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for creating a snippet, but testing in IE shows the same problem as described in the question.

Comment: ok I tried something different I am using a writable computable and delaying the focus